# How Can I Upload Photos From a Flip Phone to a Desktop

Tags: 18.04, usb, xubuntu, firefox, bluetooth

I spoke with a Consumer Cellular tech person who told me to find Bluetooth and then search for my device but I dont know where or what Bluetooth is. and in searching for a device the phone did not find my desktop computer. When I plug in the phone to the computer I get a phone message "USB not allowed". I dont know what to do next. I have Firefox, the latest version.

Comment: This seems like a question about your phone. The relevance to Ubuntu is not clear.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: My o.s. is Linux Ubuntu. When I plug the cable from a phone into computer port I get an error "USB not allowed".

Comment: Version 18.04 LTS Ubuntu. But it is Firefox 71 for the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone probably supports **PAN** protocol (*Personal Area Networking*) which allows you to send/receive files within Bluetooth proximity.  You'll need to install bluez utilities ( ***bluez-utils*** ) from a package manager to get **PAN** functionality on your computer.  After your devices are paired both supporting **PAN** you should be able to send your pictures from your phone to your computer.

Also, check to see if your USB drivers for your phone are held in Ubuntu repositories.  Ubuntu has usb driver supports for a great many devices and phones from multiple carriers.  Once the usb drivers are installed you can simply upload images from your phone to your PC via *usb cable*.

Lastly, if your phone has an external memory card slot, you can save your images on your phone to your memory card and transfer images to your computer with a memory card reader.

Let me know if you made any progress. Take care.